# Python Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'k'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s="ABC"

for k in ["isalnum()", "isalpha()", "isdigit()", "islower()", "isupper()"]:
    for c in s:
        print(c.k)
```

getting this error  "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'k' "  while executing the above code. I referred other similar questions asked on this error but could not relate to my problem, I am very new to python.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you would like to see?

Comment: I want to run methods in the outer for loop for each character of string s

Comment: @Vicky Why do you expect `c` to have an attribute `k`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to call the methods you listed on the characters of `s`.

One possibility is to use `getattr` in order to look up attributes of an object by string name:

```
>>> s = "ABC"
>>> for k in ["isalnum", "isalpha", "isdigit", "islower", "isupper"]:
...     for c in s:
...         getattr(c, k)() # get the attribute, then call it
... 
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
True
True
```

Alternatively, you can loop over the methods of the `str` class directly:

```
>>> s = "ABC"
>>> for k in [str.isalnum, str.isalpha, str.isdigit, str.islower, str.isupper]:
...     for c in s:
...         k(c)
... 
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
True
True
```

(I used the variable names you did, however I recommend at least to rename `k` to `method`.)

Comment: I get this error now "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isalnum()' "

Comment: @Vicky you forgot to remove the () from your strings.

Comment: No,I copy pasted your alternative code and got the error

Comment: @Vicky the error is on your side. My code never requests an attribute lookup for `"isalnum()"` . Maybe you forgot to save your file after editing it.

Answer (score 8):

The elements in the list are just strings. And even if they weren't, `c.k` is always going to refer to the literal attribute `k`, not the attribute corresponding to the one in the list.

You need to use `getattr`; but the parentheses are not part of the attribute name, you'll need to leave them off.

```
for k in ["isalnum", "isalpha", "isdigit", "islower", "isupper"]:
    for c in s:
        print(getattr(c, k)())
```

Comment: Thanks, but why is k not referring to its value in the list ?

Comment: @Vicky But it is.

Comment: You mean when you do `c.k`? Because you've told Python explicitly "get the attribute of c that is named 'k'", not "get the attribute of c that has the name of the element in the list".

Comment: @Vicky Yes, in your code. Add `print(k)` just under the outer `for` to see what it refers to.

Comment: @Vicky `c.k` is equivalent to `getattr(c, 'k')`. Note the quotes in the `getattr` call.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Yes when I do c.k . Doesn't Python understand that when I called c.k , k is a variable (iterating over a list) ? It should rather replace k with the current value of k and then call the attribute(value of k) on c ?

Comment: @Vicky no. `object.foo` requests an attribute with the name foo.

Comment: No, why would it do that? That would mean that you could never have local variables with the same name as any attribute on any class, as otherwise you could never call the actual attributes, which would be impossibly restrictive. As tim says, `c.k` always refers to the attribute named k.

Comment: @timgeb, so getattr method looks for the value of second argument in the local scope and then calls it on first argument ?

Comment: @Vicky Your terminology is a bit shaky, but you seem to have understood what it does. `object.foo` will give you the attribute with name foo. `foo = 'hello'; getattr(object, foo)` will give you the attribute with the name hello.

Comment: @timgeb, Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0):

You can't splice strings into code like that.

This should work:

```
import operator

s = "ABC"

for k in ["isalnum", "isalpha", "isdigit", "islower", "isupper"]:
    for c in s:
        print(operator.methodcaller(k)(c)
```

`methodcaller(method_name)` creates a new function that calls the named method on its argument. So `methodcaller("islower")` is somewhat like `lambda x: x.islower()`, and therefore `methodcaller("islower")("a")` is equivalent to `"a".islower()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972817/908494) succinctly but completely explains both what's wrong with your code, and how to make your code work.

But whenever you find yourself trying to use the string names of things instead of the things themselves, there's often a better way in Python. So, it's worth looking for that better way, and deciding if you want to use it.

In this case, what you really want is a list of string methods. And in fact, you can directly create a list of string methods:

```
for k in [str.isalnum, str.isalpha, str.isdigit, str.islower, str.isupper]:
```

That's great; these methods are first-class objects in Python, just like strings, or regular functions. (In fact, under the covers, unless you're using Python 2, they just *are* functions.) But what can you do with them?

You can call them, just like functions:

```
    for c in s:
        print(k(c))
```

---

If you want to understand how this works, you need to know how normal method calls work.

When you write this:

```
s.isalpha()
```

… there are two parts to that. First, `s.isalpha` looks up the `isalpha` method on `type(s)`, and binds it to the `s` instance, returning a bound method object that knows that it wants to call `isalpha` and that it wants to call it on `s`. Next, you call that bound method, which is does by calling `isalpha` and passing `s` as the first (`self`) argument.

So, you're just doing the same thing manually: `str.isalpha` just is the `isalpha` function, and you're calling it with `s` as the first (`self`) argument.